# Prebid.js DFP configuration

Tags: google-dfp, prebid.js

Can somebody help me with integration Prebid.js to existing DFP. I have DFP and Units are live.
I created Order-Line-items with price-priority (from 0.2 to 1.5). I also did key-values hb_pb and hb_bidder (in hb_bidder I add just "rubicon").

I also dowloaded prebid.js.
My question is what else I need to do to get it live? Where I need to add setup for ex. "rubicon id", "site id", zone and unit-id? Do I need to modify code of prebid.js script, or modify DFP code from header of my site, or I can do all from DFP?

I tried this on my site, [Hunde Netzwerk](https://hundenetzwerk.net) but after a while  i switched to AD network that give me complete solution.

Answer (score 3):

Prebid.js provides a collection of adapters for various bidders and operates in the browser hence it should be configured on your pages via javascript. You would need to configure prebid.js settings and slightly change you GPT tags

Here's a detailed annotated example of how DFP could be used in combination with Appnexus
http://prebid.github.io/dev-docs/examples/basic-example.html

This is an excerpt from that page containing prebid.js configuration section:

```
var PREBID_TIMEOUT = 700;

var adUnits = [{
    code: 'div-gpt-ad-1460505748561-0',
    sizes: [[300, 250], [300,600]],
    bids: [{
        bidder: 'appnexus',
        params: {
           placementId: '4799418'
        }
    }]
},{
    code: 'div-gpt-ad-1460505661639-0',
    sizes: [[728, 90], [970, 90]],
    bids: [{
        bidder: 'appnexus',
        params: {
           placementId: '4799418'
        }
    }]
}];

var pbjs = pbjs || {};
pbjs.que = pbjs.que || [];
```

You can also play with it on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/prebid/bhn3xk2j/4/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=bhn3xk2j

And of course you don't need to modify prebid.js library code